# Hibernate :- Could not execute JDBC batch update

Tags: hibernate

i am new in Hibernate, i am getting exception when trying to save Friend_Job object on database.

I am getting Friend and Job object from database and creating new Frien_Job object.

Test.java

```
    SessionFactory sessionFectory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFectory.openSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    Friend friend= (Friend) session.load(Friend.class, new Integer(1));
    Job job = (Job) session.load(Job.class, new Integer(3));
    Friend_Job friend_Job  = new Friend_Job();
    friend_Job.setFriend(friend);
    friend_Job.setJob(job);
    friend_Job.setCompanyName(job.getCompanyName());
    session.save(friend_Job);
    transaction.commit(); //Exception here
```

Friend_Job.hbm.xml

```
 <hibernate-mapping>
<class name="hibernateTest.Friend_Job" table="FRIEND_JOB">
    <id name="primaryKey" column="PRIMARY_KEY">
         <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="companyName" type="string" column="COMPANY_NAME"/>
    <property name="salary" column="SALARY"/>
    <many-to-one name="friend" class="hibernateTest.Friend" cascade="none" column="FK_FRIEND_ID"/>
    <many-to-one name="job" class="hibernateTest.Job" cascade="none" column="FK_JOB_ID"/>
</class>   
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Exception :-

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:90)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:266)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:365)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
at hibernateTest.Test.main(Test.java:20)
```

Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected BINARY got NUMBER

Friend_Job.java

```
public class Friend_Job {

private int primaryKey;
private String companyName;
private int salary = 0;
private Friend friend;
private Job job;
```

and else are setter and getter.

Please let me know if more info required....
Thanks in advance.

Comment: which column in the table `FRIEND_JOB` is of type binary?

Comment: @Firo :- there is no any column type binary, i don't know why this exception throwing.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `hibernate.cfg.xml`

Check
`<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`
If there is create then change to "update"
`<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>`

Answer (score 0):

> this error coused by your default string size character
>   you have two choice for solve this problem
>   1.you must up string character size
>   example

```
<property name="companyname" column="company_name" length='25' />
```

> your companyname size must little than 25
>   2. change type to text
>   example

```
<property name="companyname" column="company_name" type='text' />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Thera are 2 possibilities :
    1. Primary key issue. You are inserting the same value 2 times.
    2. You are using    
    SessionFactory factory=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); 
    for creating sessionfactory OBJECT. It used for mysql.
So use following for oracle DB:
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    for getting session.
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the reason for that exception can be due to invalid mapping, I had such a case. When I went through the 'hbm' file there was a Set mapping to a child table, where I specified the column name which is not in the child table (the column was not present in the table). The issue was solved right after I specified the proper column in mapping.
       There might be other reasons, but for now this is all I know, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is table is created in SQL but showing null values
I overcome by changing the database name and creating new tables

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and find that the problem came from the class name . i named my class order and i found that Order is a keyword

> [javax.persistence.criteria.Order]

i update my class name and every thing work efficiently

Comment: Please don't keep posting the same answer in multiple old questions. Flag as duplicate if you think they are. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645890/org-hibernate-exception-sqlgrammarexception-could-not-fetch-initial-value-for-i/53141638#53141638)

Answer (score 0):

Check for column name in table. Are they matching with what you have added. I was entering different column name in hbm.xml and in actual table,it was different.

Answer (score -1):

This error mainly occurs because data is not getting inserted.
There might be following reasons for this issue:

1. Due to duplicate values.
2. You are missing any mandatory field/column.
3. Due to wrong constraint.